# chromium: block ads when watching youtube videos

Tags: chrome, youtube

For several years, I could watch youtube videos add-free. The only think I had to do was to install javascript blocker addon (`Scriptsafe` extension for Chromium) and block the offending domains.

Couple of months ago, I started to get ads at the beginning of Youtube videos. I have not changed anything on my side, so I presumed something has changed on Youtube side.

So I have installed another extension for Chromium `Adblock for Youtube`. Unfortunately, this did not help, and I am still getting ads at the start of my videos.

How can I get rid of all Youtube ads?

## UPDATE:

I have installed `uBlock Origin` extension, and it indeed blocks youtube ads. However, I am getting errors from `Srciptsafe` extension:

```
Warning:
This extension failed to redirect a network request to data:image
png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAACklEQVR4nGMAAQAABQABDQottAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== 
because another extension (uBlock Origin) redirected it to data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==.
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem about the warning? Is it some dialog popping up and therefore enervating? Then you might want to tweak the source of the extension throwing the warning only at console ;-)

Comment: @Jaleks - actually, the warning causes a real problem. The chromium control button (the "hamburger icon") changes to yellow, as if I had unsubscribed from my account. This requires my attention, and every time I have to check what happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin). It is available on chrome and firefox [and it's open source](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock).

If you're on chrome you might also want to install the [WebSocket companion extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin-websocket/pgdnlhfefecpicbbihgmbmffkjpaplco) so that uBlock Origin can be aware of WebSocket connections and filter them.

No other extensions I have used or seen are as effective as uBlock Origin and I never see ads on YouTube unless I turn it off. The only ads that still sometimes get through are the ones served from the same domain as the website I'm visiting.

---

#### Some additional information about uBlock Origin

uBlock Origin is much more than just an ad blocker. From the [uBlock wiki:](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Blocking-mode)

> uBlock Origin is not an "ad blocker", it is a wide-spectrum blocker, which happens to be able to function as a mere "ad blocker".

To enable the most powerful features of uBlock Origin, you need to open the pop up user interface and click on the grey bar at the top to take you to the dashboard. On the first tab (settings), you can tick a box that says "I am an advanced user" After this is ticked, the pop up user interface changes and sort of resembles that of Scriptsafe.

You asked how you can use Scriptsafe alongside uBlock Origin, unfortunately I don't have any experience with Scriptsafe so I can't be certain, but it looks to me like Scriptsafe doesn't like that uBlock Origin does the same job it wants to do. This would leave you with two options: You could go to the uBlock Origin dashboard 3rd party filters tab and un-tick the lists that block scripts until you have dumbed uBlock down to a regular ad blocker. Or you could remove Scriptsafe and use uBlock Origin only instead.

I personally used NoScript on Firefox for a long time (even alongside uBlock) but have since removed it because uBlock has all the same functionality.

Steve Gibson covered uBlock Origin on "Security Now" in September 2015, this link should take you straight to the action. It's about 20 minutes long. It's good if you'd prefer a tutorial you can watch instead of reading the documentation to learn the basics. https://youtu.be/dB9zKOJJYaI?t=4910

Comment: there seems to be a conflict between `uBlock Origin` and my other extension `Sriptsafe`. I have updated my original post. Do you happen to know how to fix this conflict ?

Answer (score 2):

[uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm) should solve your problem

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/161263)

Comment: @JeffSchaller It's ok: the essential part of the answer is to use the extension called uBlock Origin. While [firexfly's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313867) is better since it provides more explanations, losynix's post is an answer.

Answer (score -5):

You should use `Adblock Plus`. Only `Adblock`, `AdBlock Plus` and `Element hiding helper for Adblock` are real, all other AdBlocks are fake.

Comment: Do you have *any* evidence to support your assertion?

Comment: Yes, just look at the developers of those addons. They have nothing to do with the original ones.

Comment: That would be a "no" then...

Comment: If it blocks ads, it has a right to be named "AdBlock". Anyone could make their own version, and if it does its job better, it has more of a right to hold that name than the originals.

Comment: They copy AdBlock name, use the similar icon, rely on AdBlock's reputation. They do much worse job than AdBlock. The question author installed one of those extensions and you see - it does not work at all. Somehow uBlock, AdAway, many others do manage to work without pretending to be that AdBlock. While those clones exist only because original AdBlock is legally grey area and will not drag them all to court.

Comment: that's false: I use Ublock Origin, and it removes most of ads. Ublock has also a "block element" option (in right click) with which I can block everything I want in a page, for example, I blocked the "fork" button of Github because I don't want to press it accidentally. Yes, the logo is red with letters in the middle, and yes, the name is similar to AdBlock, but it's not a fake. Or you were speaking about "Adblock for YouTube" only?

Comment: uBlock Origin and uBlock are different extensions by different people and a nasty background. uBlock Origin is probably the best now. uBlock should be removed.